# How to get the URL and credentials used in CRM for Outlook?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

I've developed an add-on for Outlook connecting to a CRM server. While it works and does what it's supposed to, it'd be nice to automatize the installation process by omitting the configuration by obtaining the URL and credentials that are being used in the CRMO (or whatever we call the CRM client for Outlook).

After I've looked for a while, I haven't found any pointers on how to get that information. It's also fully acceptable (if it can be done) to tunnel the records from CRM **via** the client for Outlook.

So, I'd like to know two things. How to do the following.

1. Checking if the client for Outlook is installed in the first place.
2. Fetch (or apply) the login information stored for its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at registry key - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSCRMClient`. You'll find organization URL and name there.

On-Premise installation uses windows auth to connect, so you should be able get this information in your outlook addin code. Don't know about CRM online, but my advice would be to look in same place as above

Comment: To be honest, I didn't bother to look there because I assumed that the password would be hidden elsewhere and/or encrypted beyond any retrieval (as it should be the case, of course). Perhaps I was mistaken? I'll take a peek tomorrow at work. Unless you already know what I'm going to find out... :)

Comment: Password itself will not be there - just locations. For on-premise you should be able to get password by common .NET framework method - System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. If it's CRM Online, then i don't have a clue where and how it's stored.